# JavaScript - Add img with data-pic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add an image in a `span` with **data-pic**, but now I want to try a picture carousel, how can I use JavaScript to index data-pic to achieve the effect?

I follow this instruction:

[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr)

```js
$(".product-colors span").click(function () {
  $(".product-colors span").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("body").css("background", $(this).attr("data-color"));
  $(".product-price").css("color", $(this).attr("data-color"));
  $(".product-button").css("color", $(this).attr("data-color"));
  $(".product-pic").css("background-image", $(this).attr("data-pic"));
});
```

```css
.product-colors span {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.blue {
  background: #7ed6df;
}

.green {
  background: #badc58;
}

.yellow {
  background: #f9ca24;
}

.rose {
  background: #ff7979;
}

.product-colors .active:after {
  content: "";
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #8888;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  left: -4px;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<body>
  <div class="product-card">
    <h1>A new model of free group travel</h1>
    <p>Travel destination</p>
    <div class="product-pic"></div>
    <div class="product-colors" id="Banner">
      <span class="blue active" data-color="#7ed6df" data-pic="url(1.jpg)"></span>
      <span class="green" data-color="#badc58" data-pic="url(2.jpg)"></span>
      <span class="yellow" data-color="#f9ca24" data-pic="url(3.jpg)"></span>
      <span class="rose" data-color="#ff7979" data-pic="url(4.jpg)"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
      <div class="product-price">$90</div>
      <a href="Paying.html" class="product-button">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am learning the basics of JavaScript, I don’t know how to implement this feature.

Hope you can help me

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you can't use background and background-image together, one will overwrite the other,
By the way ,what are you trying to create? a carousel or what?

Comment: for indexing you can use `each()` method

Answer (score 0):

you can't use background and background-image together, one will overwrite the other,
By the way ,what are you trying to create? a carousel or what?
well, I guess this is what you're trying to do,
in order to achieve this, you need to declare the `$('body')` twice,  add background-color to the first, then background-image to the second or (vice-versa),
below is the final code

```
var span = $('.product-colors span');
span.on('click', function() {
  span.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('body').css("background-color", $(this).attr('data-color'));
  $('body').css('background-image', $(this).attr('data-pic'));
});
```

then go the css, I added `background-blend` property to it, so as to blend the `background-color` and `background-image` together, I also set the `span` to `display: inline-block`

check out this codepen link to see all the changes made [here](https://codepen.io/victory-lucky/pen/vYXeRGx)